# How can I manage Hyper-V Server 2012 R2 from Windows 7 with PowerShell

Tags: hyper-v

I am tearing my hair out at the moment trying to do this. Just a couple of things to clear up:

1. I have Windows Hyper-V Server 2012 R2 freshly downloaded and Remote Administration enabled;
2. I have a Windows 7 Professional machine - up to date etc. etc.
3. I know you cannot manage Hyper-V 2012 R2 from Windows 7 using the GUI, that's why I want to use PowerShell;
4. I've been using PowerShell for a while but all this remote connection stuff is very new;

So with that out of the way, let's go.

I've used Connect-PSSession to connect to the PowerShell session on the Hyper-V server. No problem. Remote commands don't work (get-vm for example), I'm assuming because I don't have them installed locally. I tried to do import-pssession (which is what I use when I'm managing Office 365 with PS remotely) and that works but doesn't give me any hyper-v cmdlets to use. I have tried to import-module hyper-v and it doesn't exist.

So I'm stuck. I've been Googling for about 2 hours now with no luck. Plenty of very old articles about how to connect to Server 2008 ort 2012 from Windows 8 but nothing on how to connect to it from Windows 7.

Any help?

Comment: Making no assumptions, I presume you've imported the Hyper-V module ?

Comment: Yeah, tried that. No valid module file found. (updated original question)

Comment: You need the module on your machine and imported otherwise no cmdlets you run will be found/execute. You can install the module, it's under Windows Features -> Hyper-V -> Hyper-V Module for Windows Powershell. Once you've installed it, run Get-Module -ListAvailable to confirm it's on your system, then import the module as normal. Once imported and connected to your Hyper-V host, you can use all the cmdlets in the module such as Get-VM.

Comment: On which machine? Windows 7 doesn't have a Hyper-V option under features and the Hyper-V Server doesn't have a GUI.

Comment: You could try this library on Codeplex https://pshyperv.codeplex.com/, otherwise I don't know I'm afraid.

Comment: Cheers mate. That was last updated in 2011. Tried to install that earlier and it ended up with errors ('invalid root' being the latest)

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

1. Create a new PSSession on your Hyper-V host

```
    $Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName [Hyper-V Host] -Credential (Get-Credential)
```

2. then enter it:

```
    Enter-PSSession $Session
```

Your PowerShell prompt will change to indicate you're connected to the remote machine.  Any powershell commands you run will be ran on the remote machine.
Try it, you'll find Get-Vm now works.